# Android dx usage

Tags: android, jar, dex, dx

I have a jar file created out of an android application, because I marked it as "Is library" in eclipse at creation time. Now the DexClassLoader is not able to load this file because it doesn't have an entry marked classes.dex. This looks like a standard jar. How can I convert such a jar into a dexed jar with dx that DexClassLoader can load? Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the dx tool from the sdk, from the command line. Something like:

```
dx --dex --output=dexed.jar hello.jar
```

Works for me. Integrating such things into your build process is something of a black art, largely involving hacking up the ant buildscripts provided by the SDK. If your library is only occasionally updated it might be viable to do it manually.

In my case, I keep the dexed.jar in my resources/raw folder. At runtime, I copy it from there into the filesystem, then pass the filesystem path to the DexClassLoader. It's... a little bumpy.

Comment: My jar file contains some xml in assets folder. I want this to be a part of .dex
Any idea how to implement this ?

Comment: A part of .dex? Are you sure? I'm surprised that it's not sufficient to put them into your .apk. The only thing I can think of off the top of my head is to generate a class that contains those XML files as static string members, then dex that class.

Answer (score 0):

Android Libraries are not meant to be started on device. They only can be included as part of Android Projects, which will convert all referenced Android Library .jar files into single shared `.dex` file and package them to `.apk` file.

If you want to test your Android Library and it's manifest actually has some entry points for that, then the only way to do so is temporarily change Android Library to Android Project (by checking off that check bar in settings).